# Linux: application responsiveness and select()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost-asio, boost-thread

I have a C++ console app that uses `open() [O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK]`, `write()`, `select()`, `read()` and `close()` to work with device file. Also `ioctl()` can be called to cancel current operation. At any given time only one user can work with device.

I need to come up with C++ class having libsigc++ signals that get fired when data is available from device.

The problem: when calling `select()` application becomes unresponsive as it waits for the data. How to make it responsive - by calling `select()` in worker thread? If so - how will worker thread communicate with main thread? Maybe I should look into `boost::asio`?

Comment: Why do you call select if you don't want to _wait for_ data? If you just want to check whether data is available, use select with a timeout of zero (see `man select`).

Comment: @JonasWielicki how is timeout of zero better than waiting for specific amount of time or waiting indefinitely? If timeout is zero, then calls to select() will be executed in loop and it will block anyway. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you call select that often if you don't want to wait then?

Comment: @JonasWielicki it is not known in advance when data will become available, that is why app is waiting

Comment: Maybe you have to rethink your design. Either you have work to do, in which case you can do the work inside the `select` loop, or you don't, and then you don't mind if the `select` goes to sleep. Adding an eventfd to the fd set may be a good way to let your "work" determine when it needs to be woken up again.

Answer (score 0):

> > How to make it responsive - by calling select() in worker thread

you can use [dup()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html), this will duplicated your file descriptors... thus you can move entire read operations into another thread. thus your write thread and processing thread will be responsive, even when the read [select()] thread is in sleeping.

signal emitting overhead of libsigc++ is minimal, thus i think you can embedded code inside the read thread itself. slots can exist in different thread, this is where you will receive your signals...

I think  [Thrift](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/thrift/trunk/lib/cpp/src/thrift/) source code [entirely boost based] might be of your interest, though thrift does not use libsigc++.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you've misunderstood select; the purpose of select (or poll, epoll, etc) is not "wait for data" but "wait for one or more events to occur on a series of file descriptors or a timer, or a signal to be raised".

What "responsiveness" is going missing while you're in your select call? You said it's a console app so you're not talking about a GUI loop, so presumably it is IO related? If so, then you need to refactor your select so that waiting for the data you're talking about is one element; that is, if you're using select, build FD_SETs of ALL file/socket descriptors (and stdin and stdout are file descriptors) that you want to wait on input for.

Or build a loop that periodically calls "select" with a short timeout to /test/ for any pending input and only try and read it when select tells you there is something to read.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) style problem.  There are various way to implement a solution to this problem, but most folks these days tend to use [condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Waiting_and_signaling) based approaches (see this [C++11 based example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Example_in_C.2B.2B)).

There are also a number of design patterns that when implemented can help alleviate your concurrency problem, such as:

[Half-Sync / Half-Async](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/HS-HA.pdf)

- A producer-consumer style pattern that introduces a queue between an asynchronous layer that fills the queue with events, and a synchronous layer that processes those events.

[Leader / Followers](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/lf.pdf)

- Multiple threads take turns handling events
- A related discussion is available [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/2529).